# Git - Switch to files on new branch created remotely

Tags: git, branch

I have a repo on Github. My local Git master branch is working fine and up to date. I create a `gh-pages` branch via Github. On my local computer, I do the following:

```
git pull
git checkout -b gh-pages
```

It says I am now on the branch `gh-pages`, however all of the files in the directory are still from my `master` branch. How do I see and edit the files on the `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: Are you sure that `gh-pages` is pointing to a different commit than `master`? Perhaps you created the branch from the head of `master`, and did not introduce any changes in it?

Answer (score 2):

[Adi Levin is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105581/git-switch-to-files-on-new-branch-created-remotely#comment57932709_35105581): you have created a new, local `gh-pages` branch that is unrelated to thee `gh-pages` branch you created on github.

You don't show the "remote" name you use for github, but let's say it's `origin` (which is pretty typical).  If so, when `git pull` does the `git fetch` step to obtain new stuff for *your* repository from the git repository over on github.com, your local repository acquires a *remote-tracking branch* named `origin/gh-pages` which matches up with the `gh-pages` on the remote named `origin`.  (If you used a different name for the remote—say you called it `calvinandhobbes` for instance—you'd acquire `calvinandhobbes/gh-pages`, and so on.)

Then, you did `git checkout -b ...`.  The key here is the `-b` switch, which tells `git checkout`: *please create a new local branch, ignore all those remote branches and those other local branches I have now, just create me a new local branch*.  This means your local branch `gh-pages` is not tied in any way to your `origin/gh-pages`.

The fix is trivial: get back off your local `gh-pages` (so that you can delete the branch with `git branch -d`), then delete the branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d gh-pages
```

If you want to *keep* the branch (perhaps you made some commits on it already), just *rename* it instead—you can do this while you are on it, or after getting back off it, whichever you like:

```
git branch -m newname gh-pages
```

(`git branch` only needs the new name, rather than both new and old names, if you are still on your accidental `gh-pages`, but giving both new and old names works no matter what).

Now that you no longer have a `gh-pages` branch, tell `git checkout` to switch to your local `gh-pages` branch:

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

> **Wait, what?  We just got rid of it, we can't get on it anymore!**

Exactly.  The `git checkout` command can't get on this nonexistent branch.  So, when it *tries*, it says to itself: "Wait, hmm, there is no `gh-pages` yet.  I wonder if there's a *remote-tracking* branch named `gh-pages`?"  It looks through all your remote-tracking branches, and whoa hey, there it is!  One and only one remote-tracking `gh-pages` branch, namely `origin/gh-pages`!

What it does at this point is slightly magic: it creates you a new local branch `gh-pages`, *sort of* like the way it would with `-b`, but different: the new `gh-pages` is set to start from the same commit as `origin/gh-pages`, *and*, the new `gh-pages` is also set up to *track* the remote-tracking branch.

That is, `git checkout gh-pages` winds up doing:

```
git checkout -b --track gh-pages origin/gh-pages
```

(Compare with the command you ran, without `--track` and without `origin/gh-pages`: the difference is *where `gh-pages` starts* and *that the new branch is set up with an upstream branch, namely `origin/gh-pages`*.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the branch and set your remove branch as tracking branch:

`git branch gh-pages -t origin/ghpages`

`-t` is to set the remote tracking branch.

Then you can use it.